# winform cannot call SOAP WS after deployment

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services, soap

I have a created a webservice which works perfectly. I have created a small winform app to test the WS. Winform app works perfectly too. I deployed the WS to the SERVER, and trying to call the WS from its new address, but I am getting the following error

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

my config file like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Service1Soap" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/Service1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="Service1Soap" contract="OdeAlWS.Service1Soap"
                name="Service1Soap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I can call the WS on my local machine, because I added the WS to my winform app automatically with Visual Studio. But, now I have to fix the config manually because I cannot reach the SERVER with my Visual Studio

How can I fix this my config, so it can call the WS?

Comment: You can start by changing localhost to the name of the server. Depending on how your network is configured, you may need to use the fully qualified name for the server.

Comment: If that doesn't work you may need to drop the reference to the local service and use the wizard to create one to the service on the server.

Comment: I cannot create the referencne bu Visual Studio, WS cannot be accessed from outside

Comment: Then if changing the endpoint does not work, you may need to hand modify the proxy class that the wizard created when you created the local reference.